# issue with play video in background using swift 3

Tags: swift3, avfoundation

i have an app the download video from internet and playing it through my app i need to playing the video in background when the user exit from the app it still working how can i perform this task i try some question on site stack overflow but can't fix my problem and i add theses following code to make it and also not working

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
        if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.remoteControlPlay {
            print("Play")
        }
    }
```

and also i add the following code in the Appdelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let getAvAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
          try getAvAudioSession.setActive(true)
          try getAvAudioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
    return true
}
```

and i also enable background mode in the app from the capabilities also not working

please can fix it me

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Look into importing MediaPlayer. Something like below.

```
import MediaPlayer

let mpic = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

func setupNowPlayingInfoCenter() {
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    mpic.playCommand.addTarget {event in
        print("playCommand")
        self.player?.play()
        return .success
    }
    mpic.pauseCommand.addTarget {event in
        print("pauseCommand")
        if self.player?.rate != 0 {
            self.player?.pause()
        }
        return .success
    }
    mpic.nextTrackCommand.addTarget {event in
        print("nextTrackCommand")
        return .success
    }
    mpic.previousTrackCommand.addTarget {event in
        print("previousTrackCommand")
        return .success
    }

}
```

Don't know if you really want to start your audio session in Appdelegate, but thats up to you. Basically call setupNowPlayingInfoCenter() when you start your playing.

Comment: This is not correct:  `setupNowPlayingInfoCenter()` should be launched to the `viewDidLoad` method , you shouldn't call it every time you start to play something or you close the `MPRemoteCommandCenter`